# ValueError: Layer concatenate_1 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, keras-layer

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(concatenate([image_model, lang_model], axis=1))
model.add(LSTM(1000,return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dense(self.vocab_size))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
```

str(inputs) + '. All inputs to the layer '
ValueError: Layer concatenate_1 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor. Received type: . Full input: [, ]. All inputs to the layer should be tensors.

Comment: Dumping an error log is not like asking a question. Can you formulate a proper question and show what have you tried to solve the problem so far?

Answer (score 0):

You need a Functional API model to create models with branches.

```
out = Concatenate(axis=1)([image_model.output,lang_model.output])
out = LSTM(...)(out)
out = Dense(...)(out)
out = Activation('softmax')(out)

model = Model([image_model.input, lang_model.input], out)
```